# Finding all the classes that inherit an interface in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I find out about a new interface, does Visual Studio provide any means to find out all the classes that have inherited that interface?

No,I don't want the C# code to do that..I know that's available at stackoverflow itself.I just want to know if Visual Studio has any functionality to find out this info for any interface through intellisense or any shortcut??

Comment: classes don't inherit interfaces they implement them, I'm you knew that already though :)

Comment: On the screen,they inherit before implementing..don't they? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, VS can do it.

Go to the Object Browser, **select .Net Framework v*X***,  then navigate to an interface and expand Derived Types.

In VS2010, this feature is available in all views, but in earlier versions, it's only available in a complete framework list.

As other people have noted, [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) can also do this, and, unlike Resharper, it is free.

Comment: Object Explorer works well...Howeever,I wish there was some way to get this info directly from intellisense. I guess that's made possible only by commercial apps...

Comment: Unfortunately Reflector is not free anymore..

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio does not have this functionality. [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Type_Hierarchy) does. I think the closest you can get is right click on the interface and select `Find All References`.

Comment: Thanks Darin ...Resharper is a commercial tool tho...I wish there were free ones to do this...

Answer (score 1):

[Reflector does](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), it is free and excellent. Search for the interface name and expand the "Derived Types" node.